# Node.js - npm test <package> silently succeeded without any output?

Tags: node.js

npm test is a cool way to check the package. Output says 'npm is not ok' if package has some issue.

```
# npm test transkode
```

While if default test script passes it doesn't show any output.
Can we enable the logs for test?

I did search in node.js google group and found that test output was enabled in older releases.
 [see some discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/npm-/browse_thread/thread/a40f67b91271dcb4?pli=1).

Also i don't see any option in npm documentation for this [NPM Test documentation](http://npmjs.org/api/test.html)

What option is required to enable output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`npm test package` will [run a package's test script](http://npmjs.org/doc/test.html), where the test script is configured in the [package.json](http://npmjs.org/doc/scripts.html) file. It's up to the package's author to create a test script that will actually output the test's results.

For example, in a sample CoffeeScript package's package.json, I have

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "cake test"
},
```

So `npm test myPackage` will invoke `cake test`. My Cakefile then has a test task that looks like this:

```
task 'test', 'test against the specs', ->
    command = extify 'jasmine-node'
    args = ['--coffee', 'spec/']
    jasmine = spawn command, args
    jasmine.stdout.on 'data', (data) -> print data.toString()
    jasmine.stderr.on 'data', (data) -> print data.toString()
```

Which uses jasmine-node to run the tests. The results of the tests appear in the console.

Comment: I don't know if you're testing transkode, but it doesn't include a test script section in package.json which is why you wouldn't see any output.

Comment: o yeah, transkode doesn't have any test script. i checked with npm view transkode. thanks...